# Gravador de Voz com Pause

Tags: android, áudio

Eu estive procurando, mas não encontrei nada, o máximo que achei foram gravadores com apenas o stop, minha aplicação o pause é essencial. Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Tu vai ter que fazer com o `AudioRecorder` senão me engano, ele permite que tu trabalhe com um stream RAW do áudio. O pause basicamente seria parar o microfone e a escrita do teu stream, e o resume seria continuar isso. Problema é, o áudio vem RAW, então tu tem que fazer toda a parte de enconding do áudio.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de como se faz isso? E obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Exemplo tem até aqui no SO en: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499042/android-audiorecord-example. Android Dev tem a documentação da classe também http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html  Como eu disse, pra pausar, é "só" tu não fechar o stream do arquivo, mas parar de gravar o stream do audio. Boa sorte :)